# Green Function for Different a Differential Operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform, dirac-delta, greens-function

Good afternoon everyone. I am solving a hard PDE and, in doing so, I ended up needing to solve
$${\bf r}\cdot\nabla\psi = f({\bf r})$$
where $\nabla$ and ${\bf r}$ are in 2D and the source term $f$ can be almost anything. Hence, I wanted to solve this using Green's function and leaving the solution as an integral, if it cannot be solved analytically for the given $f$. So, I must solve
$$ {\bf r}\cdot\nabla G = \delta({\bf r} - {\bf r'})$$

My first attempt was to use Fourier's transform on this equation, but it turns out that
$$\mathcal{F}(tf'(t))) = i\omega\mathcal{\tilde{f}(\omega)} + \mathcal{F}(tf(t))=i\omega\tilde{f}(\omega) + i\tilde{f}'(\omega) $$
if my math is right (which I am not 100% sure). In this case, my overall equation would still involve a derivative, which does not help much.

Does somebody know of a way to solve such an equation? What could I try in this scenario?

Comment: That is effectively a transport equation but where the matter of what is time and what is 1D space is not clear. What kind of boundary condition do you have?

Comment: Well, there is no time, as $\psi=\psi(x, z)$ and $f=f(x, z)$. As for the boundary conditions, there are quite a few options, but vanishing at infinity is true for most (the equations stems from plasma dynamics, so $\psi$ is the pressure profile in the plasma, which is zero outside it, so there are some more considerations). Having an idea how to approach it would be great.

Comment: I mean that to treat it as a transport equation you need to at least locally decide on something to be "time" and something to be "space". Just vanishing at infinity doesn't uniquely specify anything here.

Comment: What sort of boundary condition would, then, be enough?

Comment: That depends on the geometry. If one axis or the other is not in the domain then you can pick a variable to be "time" (divide through by whichever variable is going to play the role of time) and follow the method of characteristics. If not, then you have a harder problem.

Comment: You can use method of characteristics. Are you specifically asked to use Greens functions?

Comment: I am not asked to solve it anyway, as it is more a research problem. I liked the idea of Greens functions, because it minimizes my efforts when I need to test new functions $f$. I am currently testing the characteristics method.

Comment: I know this is old, but I wanted to give my 25 cents. I like your idea of trying to reduce the problem using Fourier Transforms as it's what I would do for Poisson's Equation. Could you edit the problem a bit to clarify how **r** is oriented? If the geometry is circular, then r should be normal to the circumference and the gradient is always normal to the boundary of any surface and that would make them parallel which would make the dot product something you could simply write out. I think you need to make cases based on the geometry like case(i) circular shape, (ii)elliptical, (iii) irregular